# fgets() is being weird when scanning lines that contain a % symbol

Tags: c, string, file-io

This is part of a school project, so I can't show anybody my code, but suffice to say, my project has to read, copy, and edit its own source code (because we're studying polymorphic malware). I'm using fgets() to read each line of code, but whenever I have a line of code with a modulo operation or format string, the % symbol and whatever non-whitespace character that comes after it is missing. I'm guessing that fgets() is treating that % symbol like a format string, so how do I tell it not to do that?

Post answer edit:
I am posting one line of code to demonstrate what was wrong.
This is how I was getting strings from a file:

```
fgets(line, 128, src_file);
```

This is how I was writing that string to a new file (which was wrong)

```
fprintf(out_file, line);
```

Comment: How do you determine that the character is missing?

Comment: The code writes itself to a new file for editing.

Comment: I'm guessing you're outputting it with `printf()` without format string?

Comment: I am using fprintf(). But yeah, there is no format string.

Comment: @Inglonias Show me how you are using `fprintf()`. Just that one line will be enough

Comment: Give us some code. Otherwise it's difficult to discuss (the questions you are getting illustrate this). YOu don't have to show everything. Just provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: fprintf(out_file, line);
I'm guessing I should be using fprintf(out_file,"%s",line);

Comment: If you're printing an arbitrary string with a `printf`-like function, you *must* use `printf("%s", string)`, *never* `printf(string)`.

Comment: Meta comment: you should produce a minimal example anyway (cudos to ace to have the right idea without any code). That it is a school project shouldn't be in the way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `fprintf(out_file, line)` is wrong.

When `line` contains the `%` character, it will be interpreted by `fprintf()` as a format specifier, which is not what you want.

You should change it to `fprintf(out_file, "%s", line)` instead.

Comment: You're very good at this to be able to identify what the problem is with no code (and again, sorry about that).

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to write a string to a file you better use [`fputs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs):

```
fputs(line, out_file);
```